# Hibernate changes way of id generation after using @JoinTable annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, h2

I have two entities having many to many relation. Relation table is also mapped ad entity. It has id column with IDENTITY strategy.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
public class Employee { 
    // ...
 
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(
        name = "Employee_Project", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "project_id") }
    )
    Set<Project> projects = new HashSet<>();
   
    // standard constructor/getters/setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Project")
public class Project {    
    // ...  
 
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "projects")
    private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();
    
    // standard constructors/getters/setters   
}

@Table
public class EmployeeProject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "EmployeeProjectId", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EmployeeId", nullable = false)
    private Employee employee;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ProjectId", nullable = false)
    private Project project;
}
```

If Employee entity doesn't have @JoinTable mapping generation SQL looks like this:

`create table EmployeeProject (EmployeeProjectId integer generated by default as identity`

However after adding @JoinTable mapping in Employee generation SQL changes to this:

`create table EmployeeProject (EmployeeProjectId integer not null`

How can I force hibernate to always generate first version of SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, and you also shouldn't. If you want to model the `EmployeeProject` entity, then you should also use it, i.e. map the many-to-many association as two one-to-many associations:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
public class Employee { 
    // ...
 
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    Set<EmployeeProject> projects = new HashSet<>();
   
    // standard constructor/getters/setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Project")
public class Project {    
    // ...  
 
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "project")
    private Set<EmployeeProject> employees = new HashSet<>();
    
    // standard constructors/getters/setters   
}
```

Comment: Why I shouldn't?

Comment: Because mapping the same table multiple times can lead to issues in Hibernate. Changing the "logical collection" by persisting/removing/updating `EmployeeProject` entities can lead to inconsistencies when the many-to-many collections are also involved in a transaction.

Comment: Is that described in hibernated docs somewhere? My example is simple but in real world applications relation table often have additional columns with extra information about relation. I have to have extra entity for relation table if I want to access additional table. 

In my case mapping with JoinTable is used only to build JPA queries.

Comment: I don't think this is mentioned explicitly in the docs, but I hope you can imagine that doing this can lead to issues. If you have an entity that maps the join table, then split up the `@ManyToMany` associations into `@OneToMany` associations that refer to the entity which maps the join table. Join table mappings are always a hassle and should IMO be avoided, because at some point, a column will sneak in and then the whole mapping is broken. I'd suggest you always map the join table as entity, then you have less trouble later.